# Customizing woocommerce/plugin/checkout/review.order.php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm customizing woocommerce checkout review-order.php with following code, but it get double after loading,

```
<table>
    <center><h4>MAKE PAYMENT</h4>
    <p>Please select the following payment method</p>
</table>
```

[image: woocommerce/plugin/checkout/review.order.php]

Note: if i add any filter in my theme function.php file my checkout page keep loading, i have no idea why?

Anyone please help!

Thank You

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks!


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I would need to know what your are trying to achieve in your customisation, with code specifics, and the filter's code that returns an error. Also, if you can pitch in console output for ajax calls that are failing, that would allow better analysis of your issue.

Comment: here is the link: http://www.kliaporter.com/checkout/ , i'm not really good in coding, so i'm enable to show you console output for ajax. but if you like to view the whole file i can send email with function.php file or review-order.php, really appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: well as it is it wont help me if you don't have a sandbox where i can do many checkouts without actually purchasing anything. i tried and i see your "double" issue, that is most likely just that your label is in the foreach loop to display payment methods. post the code for your review-order.php file. ill answer here

Comment: here is the link for the review-order.php, [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Glzns1z3EndlVhYmtuREQ0MHc) Thanks :)

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper are you able to open the link?

Comment: its caused by custom code for your checkout. to solve it for you i would need access to the whole site but i can give you pointers. It is caused by an ajax request, that i am certain of. instead of updating this region, it is appending, that i would not know why. look in assets/js/frontend/checkout.js for triggers (
    init_checkout,
    update_checkout,
    updated_checkout,
    checkout_error,
)look at interactions with your review_order. alternatively, if you can find a way to not use a custom checkout process, it should solve your issue as it is not marked as a bug on github.

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper I have tried and i don't think so i can do that, since i'm not really good in coding, anyway here is the link for the assets/js/frontend/checkout.js [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Glzns1z3EnTFVpY1VRUnNFYXM) if you think you can manage to find out the trigger and solve it, that would be greate, otherwise i'm going to suggest it as well not customize checkout review order details there. Thank  You very Much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works fine at my end, but i think the problem  is you forgot to close a `<center>` tag.

close it, that may fix your problem.

Comment: yes i forgot that once i'm sending file to you, but adding the whole code in the php file its always getting double in checkout review order table...

Comment: where is the file?

Comment: i had a conversation with Ralph and i have attached the link file there, you can view it there, but its solved now.... Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

To be clearer than my comment, you need to handle what happens with your custom table from the backend.

Give your table an ID

```
<table ID="MyCustomTableId">
    <center><h4>MAKE PAYMENT</h4></center>
    <center><p>Please select the following payment method</p></center>
</table>
```

And from the backend, look in assets/js/frontend/checkout.js for triggers:

- init_checkout
- update_checkout
- updated_checkout
- checkout_error

On the AJAX callbacks, handle your table (simply replace the HTML of your table by the one of your request; it will stop duplicating at that point). Here is an example:

```
init_checkout: function() {
        $( '#billing_country, #shipping_country, .country_to_state', '#MyCustomTableId' ).change();
        $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
    },
```

emphasis on the '#MyCustomTableId' added in the list! Do that on all triggers and it should solve your issue. It will also fail every time you update woocommerce, so think about it! (It's not the end of the world, you'll get good at it, but ya' know... sustainability is a factor and who knows when one of us gets hit by a bus...)